# Passing a string argument to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

I tested the following codes many times. It works well and I get the result of "return photoMenu_sb.ToString();" as soon as I remove the string argument photoFileName. But when I declare and try to pass the string photoFileName nothing happens. Why?

I think the problem lies in declaring and passing the string photoFileName to the javascript function but I can't identify the problem since I don't get any error. Is there any missing quotations somewhere?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadPhotosPopup(int offset, int fetch, string IDuserInput)
{
        StringBuilder photosPopup_sb = new StringBuilder();           
        var photosPopup_query = db.Query("SELECT IDphoto], [photoFileName] FROM [photos] WHERE ([IDuser] = @0 AND [photoPublished] = 'True')  ORDER BY [photoDate] DESC OFFSET @1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @2 ROWS ONLY", IDuserInput, offset, fetch);
        foreach (var item in photosPopup_query)
        {
            var IDphoto = item.IDphoto;
            var photoFileName = item.photoFileName;
            photosPopup_sb.Append("<img src=\"Images/Design/openmenu.png\" onclick=\"photoMenu(" + IDphoto + ", '" + photoFileName + "') \" />");                         
         }           
        return photosPopup_sb.ToString();
    }
```

JavaScript

```
function photoMenu(IDphoto, photoFileName) {   
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UserControls/photosFunctions.aspx/photoMenu",
    data: "{ IDphoto: " + IDphoto + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#CommentsMenu" + IDphoto).html(data.d);
    }
})
```

}

```
[WebMethod]
            {   StringBuilder photoMenu_sb = new StringBuilder();                        
        photoMenu_sb.Append("<label>Testing </label>");
        return photoMenu_sb.ToString();
    }
```

UPDATE
Since the public static string photoMenu(int IDphoto, string photoFileName)
expects 2 arguments then

```
 data: "{ IDphoto: " + IDphoto + "}", in the javascript function should be 
 data: "{ IDphoto: " + IDphoto + ", photoFileName: '" + photoFileName + "'}",
```

Comment: What's the `item.IDphoto` type?

Comment: the item.IDphoto is int

Comment: In your javascript function `photoMenu(IDphoto, photoFileName)` I don't see where `photoFileName` is being used?

Comment: I'll use it later once I succeed to pass the parameter (photoFileName) first to the javascript function ...

Comment: I think that's why it's failing because the ajax call is expecting a data parameter with `photoFileName` as well. I've edited my answer to include this, you could try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: @chridam Thanks for your comment. It drew my attention to the fact that I was passing only one variable (IDphoto) to the "public static string photoMenu" which requires the 2 arguments (IDphoto and photoFileName) .... I feel like my IQ is -1000 now.... LOL! I've updated my question

Comment: LOL, no worries, hope it's working now?

Comment: I saw your answer.... One final thing plz update your answer by adding the quotaion marks as follows data: "{ IDphoto: " + IDphoto + ", photoFileName: '" + photoFileName + "'}",

Comment: That's now been updated for you, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a string variable that holds the javascript function string:

```
var img = String.Format("<img src='Images/Design/openmenu.png' onclick='photoMenu({0},'{1}')' />", item.IDphoto, item.photoFileName);
photosPopup_sb.Append(img);
```

In your JavaScript, you need to also set the json data property for the photofileName parameter:

```
function photoMenu(IDphoto, photoFileName) {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UserControls/photosFunctions.aspx/photoMenu",
        data: "{ IDphoto: " + IDphoto + ", photoFileName: '" + photoFileName + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           $("#CommentsMenu" + IDphoto).html(data.d);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Try single quotes in the place of the escaped double quotes - editing my answer to reflect this

Comment: Still nothing ..... However when I remove photoFileName and I stop passing it to the JavaScript function then the code works well. var img = String.Format("<img src='Images/Design/openmenu.png' onclick='photoMenu({0})' />", item.IDphoto);

Comment: And if you remove the single quotes inside the `photoMenu` function like `...'photoMenu({0}, {1})', item.IDphoto, item.photoFileName);`?

Comment: You need to inspect what `item.photoFileName` is returning, @Shannon raised some very valid points: it could be that the filename can have incorrectly formatted file path? Just my $0.02

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a parenthesis ")":

```
photosPopup_sb.Append("<img src=\"Images/Design/openmenu.png\" onclick=\"photoMenu(" + IDphoto + ", '" + photoFileName + "')\" />");
```

Comment: There is a paranthesis in my original code. I must have deleted it by mistake while typing the codes in here. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an example value of your `photoFileName` but if it has backslashes, you would probably have to make sure that the string is escaped properly.

For example:

```
//causes errors
called(1, 'file\path\img.png');

//successful
called(1, 'file/path/img.png');
```